# Does calling fork() in a multithreaded program block all threads?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Does calling fork() in a multithreaded program block all threads? Or will it just block the calling thread?

('calling fork()' refers to the process of creating a child process.)

Comment: Where have you got the information about fork blocking a caller? Fork blocks nothing.

Comment: Fork in a multithreaded program is almost always a mistake. http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Fork is de-facto undefined behavior in an application with multiple active threads.

Comment: There's a scenario in which fork() is commonly used in a multithreaded application: to allow to `exec(2)` a new program in a different process.  For this it is necessary to use fork() as you need a new virtual space and exec() overwrites it completely.  If you execute an exec() call in a multithreaded application you will see all your threads diying.

Answer (score 5):

> - The child process is created with a single thread—the one that
>   called fork().  The entire virtual address space of the parent
>   is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes,
>   condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of
>   pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems
>   that this can cause.
> - After a fork() in a multithreaded program, the child can
>   safely call only async-signal-safe functions (see
>   signal-safety(7)) until such time as it calls execve(2).

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

Comment: You should probably add a statement about the parent's threads not being blocked.

Comment: _the states of mutexes_, but the mutexes themselves are different, as they protect unerlated variables (original protect parent process' variables and new protect child's variables)  The pthread objects exist, but no thread is running for them.

Answer (score 2):

> Does calling `fork()` in a multithreaded program block all threads? Or will it just block the calling thread?

The `fork()` function does not block anything *per se*.  In particular, **it returns as soon as it gets the new child process started, without waiting for the child to terminate**.  Thus, unless the child is exceedingly short-lived, after a `fork()` returns successfully there are two processes running where there had been one.  This is the source of the name "fork".

Naturally, `fork()` is not instantaneous, and in fact it is likely to be somewhat expensive.  The thread that calls it cannot proceed until it returns, as those are the semantics of threads and function calls.  Other threads in the same process are not affected, and, as your other answer observes, they are not propagated to the new process, either.

Comment: It can return as soon as it knows the child process will be correctly built.  The only thing that can block fork() from return is an error in building the child.  The child process doesn't need to be running at all, for the parent to return from `fork()`

Answer (score 0):

The term process in unix like operating systems, and its difference with a thread of execution is that all threads in a process share the same virtual space memory.  In other aspects, they are completely different running processes.  Each has it's own stack pointer (for user an kernel mode, as two threads can be simultaneously executing a system call, and have switched their stack to kernel stack, so there's a kernel stack per thread) so there's no reason for a system call in one thread to block or interrupt a system call in another  as it is possible for two different processes to be executing a system call simultaneously (except the obvious ones `kill(2)`, `read(2)` or `write(2)`, these last that block only if the two read's act upon the same file, which is locked during the time of the system call to serialize/sequence reads/writes to the same file)

Apart of these, the `fork()` call is a call that *starts in one process, and ends in two.*  So the fork() in the parent and the fork in the child behave as if both were started at the same time (in case you have a timestamp of the starting point of each call you will have the exact same timestamp, because the call was started only once, and the timestamp will need to be copied)  but as they have two different ends, these can be in any order, or with small difference or high (depending on the system load).  Nothing blocks a fork() except the allocation of the resources for the child to start (but when the child starts the parent can gone far away, or even died).  This can make the parent to continue after the fork() (but not as soon as the kernel knows if there are enough resources to build the child process, as the fork should give an error to the parent in case something goes wrong) quite early in the full system call, that remains building (with the new thread) the process table entry, the user area of the process, and the first thread of it, and returning `0` after that.

As you have been told, all thread related stuff is "copied" into the child, but as the child is not multithreaded, there are no threads to use that memory, but this is also not an issue, as while the process doesn't use it, it is not allocated (in pages of actual memory) actually (or it is allocated in swap space, if the parent decides to change it, using the Copy On Write feature)

The normal case of making a fork in a multithreaded process is when you need to execute another program.  In that case, `fork()` is going to be followed quickly by an `exec()` that will garbage collect all the unused memory.  Think this way... if you need a completely new virtual space, then you need fork.... if you want to share the memory between threads, then create a new thread.